# C-Shell regex compare a variable with two strings

Tags: regex, csh, tcsh

This returns 1:

`if ( "$TERM" =~ "xterm*" ) echo 1`

but these return nothing:

`if ( "$TERM" =~ "(xterm*|rxvt*)" ) echo 1`

`if ( "$TERM" =~ "(xterm|rxvt)*" ) echo 1`

How am I supposed to do OR regex comparisons in csh? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Comment: I would happily avoid using this nerve-racking language if it was not the default in the server I am using !Machine and ssh-ing to...

Comment: I don't know about csh, but you probably should remove quotes around your pattern.

Comment: Also `*` in your pattern doesn't look right. What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: You don't have to use the same shell for scripting as your default login shell.

Comment: I am changing the .cshrc ....

Comment: You're mixing up glob and regex syntax. `xterm*` is glob, the equivalent regex would be `^xterm.*`

Comment: Oh, then never mind ....

Answer (score 2):

The right-hand operand in **C-Shell**'s `=~` operator is not a **RegEx** pattern but a **glob** pattern.
From [this documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/csh) I found:

> The operators '=~' and '!~' are like '!=' and '==' except that the right hand side is a glob-pattern (see Filename substitution) against which the left hand operand is matched.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a way to do regex comparisons then in this language? Is using `grep` the only solution?

Comment: @VasilisLemonidis For this pattern you can probably use brace expansion: `=~ {xterm,rxvt}*` – not 100% sure that will work (didn't test it), but IIRC tcsh implements it. Otherwise you'll have to use grep, yeah.

Comment: It works! Please write an anwer so that I can accept it and you get your points :)